# querystring encryption

Tags: perl, encryption, query-string

I am working in *perl*. I need `querystring` encryption for edit page.

Now I am passing `querystring` as `?id=1` which is to be

`?id=hjjkdty4567778xvcvbqeweretrtryfghghgcg5677rffhjvj`  like that.

Does anyone know anything regarding this?

Comment: Dear user1852579, please ask any difficulty you came across. SO is not discussion forum.

Comment: It isn't completely obvious to me how to encode `1` as `hjjkdty4567778xvcvbqeweretrtryfghghgcg5677rffhjvj`. I'm feeling close but I don't understand it completely.

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you have information in a URL that you want to encrypt.

If all you want is that the query string isn't immediately readable then something simple like rot13 encoding may be suitable. Take a look at [`Crypt::Rot13`](http://search.cpan.org/~ayrnieu/Crypt-Rot13-0.6/Rot13.pm).

If you need more secure encrypting than that then another of the `Crypt::` modules will suit your purpose, so take a look on CPAN.

Comment: Two be *really* secure, apply rot13 twice :)